# List in a jsonObject

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-recyclerview

I have response from server in this way:

```
{
"ownerName": "theName",
"site": "theSite",
"group": "theGroup",
"honours": [
 {
    "id": 189,
    "name": "Assistant Professor"
}, {
    "id": 226,
    "name": "of the Four Winds"
}, {
    "id": 227,
    "name": " Defender of a Shattered World"
}, {
    "id": 228,
    "name": "Dragonslayer %s"
}, {
    "id": 229,
    "name": " Blackwing's Bane"
}, {
    "id": 278,
    "name": "Firelord %s"
}, {
    "id": 342,
    "name": " Storm's End"
}, {
    "id": 477,
    "name": "Fabulous",
    "selected": true
}]
}
```

I would like to access the list and set a `TextView#setText` to include both the `ownerName` and the `name` in the `honours` list. I use `RecyclerView.Adapter#onBindVewHolder` in this way after looping and parsing the `json` response with the POJO model.

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CharacterTitlesAdapter.CharacterTitlesViewHolder holder, int position) {

    CharacterTitleModel item = characterTitleModels.get(position);

    holder.itemView.setTag(item);

    Log.d("Titles size: ", String.valueOf(item.getTitles().size()));

    for(int i = 0; i < item.getTitles().size(); i++){

    TitleModel lt = item.getTitles().get(i);

    holder.titleName.setText(lt.getName().replace("%", item.getCharacterName() + "'"));

    }
```

When i loop through the list as in above, i only get the last item on the list. If i use the `int position` i get the first item on the list.

How do i access **ALL** the items in the list of the JSON response.

P.S.: i know i can primarily just parse only the `honours` json array, but i need the `ownerName`.

Every help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the `ownerName`, use `HashMap`, use the `put` method to insert the values of the `ownerName`, `site` etc. Then use `ArrayList` to `addAll` the `honours` array. In the example below, the `hashMap` is declared already:

```
    ResponseModel responseModel = gson.fromJson(theJsonResponse,
            ResponseModel.class);

    hashMap.clear();
    hashMap.put("response", responseModel);
```

Then in `RecyclerView.onBindViewHolder` use the `hashMap.get(Object key)` to obtain the values:

`final ResponseModel item = hashMap.get("response");`

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to get the honours JSON Array, then you should be able to extract the ownerName as well.

You'll want to do something similar to below:

```
JSONObject root = new JSONObject(yourJSONString);
String ownerName = root.getString("ownerName");
JSONArray honoursArray = root.getJSONArray("honours");
```

Then grab what you need from the honoursArray

Comment: If i parsed only the honours array, i wont have access to the ownerName in the **RecyclerView#onBindViewHolder**, because i would be using a HonoursModel, so i hope for syntax or method in the `onBindViewHolder`, to enable me get access to both the `ownerName` and `honours` array.

Comment: Where did you parse the JSON originally? What does your Model class look like? There&#39;s really not enough information here to help further.

Why don't you post your full adapter class and your Model class.